# What is the difference between the Amish and Mennonites?

Tags: comparative-christianity, amish, mennonite

I've heard of different groups, typically technology-rejecting ones, being referred to as "Amish" or "Mennonite". Is there a difference between those two terms? What do these groups believe?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mennonites#Jacob_Amman_and_the_Amish_schisms would imply the Amish split off from the Mennonites

Comment: I have some close friends who live near by who attend [Center Amish Mennonite Church](https://plus.google.com/117442899387107830860/about?gl=us&hl=en). So in a sense, asking the difference between the Amish and Mennonites is like asking the difference between a collie and a dog. In a lot of ways, the Amish are a subset of the Mennonites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the Amish (aka Amish Mennonites) are a group that broke off from the Mennonites in Switzerland in 1693, led by Jakob Ammann, from which the name comes.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mennonite#Jacob_Amman_and_the_Amish_schisms)

While Amish reject many modern technological advancements, Mennonites have a broader range of acceptance of such things.  Some Mennonites are quite similar to the Amish, while others accept all modern technology.  I had a friend in college who was Mennonite, and he drove a car, used computers and did everything else.

[Amish reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amish)

Comment: I had a Mennonite professor of religion in college - he was also a multi-degree black belt (and instructor) in Mui Thai Kickboxing

Comment: @warren So, I take it you got all your homework assignments in on time?

Comment: I did ;) .. and I went to his MTK class one night, too - very interesting fellow

Comment: I'm a Mennonite, and I know of at least one or two other regulars here who are as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Amish and Mennonites are very similar in most of their basic religious beliefs. However the way they live and dress etc. is different from a lot of Mennonites. "Mennonite" is a very broad term ranging from those who drive horse and buggy and are very similar to the Amish and those who pretty much blend in with the world.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).
For some tips on writing good answers here, see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394)

Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.